# Cannot connect to MQTT broker(mosquitto) with Javascript Ionic

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, mqtt, paho

I tried to bind MQTT with the Ionic framework. When trying to send an MQTT message to the broker (I am publishing), when a click event occurs, I get the following error:

> "AMQJS0011E Invalid state not connected......"
>   "WebSocket connection to 'ws://test.mosquitto.org:8080/mqtt' failed: Error >during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET"

Please can anyone help me? I cannot find a solution anywhere.

I also tried with port 1883, but the problem remains the same.

```
var App = angular.module("App",["ionic","ngWebSocket"]);

App.controller("Appctrl",["$scope","$log",Appctrl]);

function Appctrl($scope,$log,$websocket){

$scope.mqtt_on = function() {

   client = new Paho.MQTT.Client("test.mosquitto.org",    
   Number(8080),"zsrgdxrgdt");
   client.connect();
   message = new Paho.MQTT.Message("Hello");
   message.destinationName = "test/smit";
   client.send(message);
   alert("ON");
};

$scope.mqtt_off = function() {
   alert("Off");
`enter code here`};

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Paho Javascript](https://eclipse.org/paho/clients/js/) client is asynchronous, the `connect` function will return before the connection is complete

So the call to `send` is being made before the connection is complete.

The `connect` function can take a argument which can contain a callback function to call once the connection is complete. So something like this should work

```
client.connect({onSuccess: function(){
  message = new Paho.MQTT.Message("Hello");
  message.destinationName = "test/smit";
  client.send(message);
}});
```